# Text box which allow numbers with currency format for viewOnly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a text box for entering amount.In that box I need to allow amount with comma formate Like

```
100 => 100

1000 =>1,000

10000 => 10,000

100000 => 100,000
```

For this I found one [link](http://codepen.io/SoEzPz/pen/mAgXOW?editors=1010).

But in this like the text box is not showing the currency format properly, Some times even not working for Example `300120`. If you enter that number it is not showing any commas.

**NOTE** The commas should not assign to ng-model. The commas should be view only. Can anyone help me out with a simple directive.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that a comma is used in German speaking countries to separate the decimal places (ie. 3,141 < 10).

Comment: Might be, But there is a requirement that need to add commas

Comment: Try this- http://plnkr.co/edit/mO257aew7YKXaIzSwS6G?p=preview

Comment: @ISHIDA will it effect to ng-model?

Comment: No, it will not effect ng-model